# SQL - Separate results by associated vale?

Tags: php, mysql

Before anything, I'll show you my table:

[image: post_tags]

(In the context of PHP)
I'd like to create a multidimensional array via a query - So that a group of *tags* with the same *id* will end up in the same place:

```
<?php

  // Given the above example table, it would essentially produce this:

  $my_1 = array
            ( array('ect'),
              array('123', 'tag'),
              array('lolly', 'hat')
            );
```

Is that a possibility? I've achieved the same result by looping through queries, but it's terribly inefficient.

Comment: Don't use separate variables, use a 2-dimensional array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

  $array = array();
  foreach($tags as $tag)
  {
    if(array_key_exist($tag->id,$array)){
      //if key is assigned in array, we can push value to key
      $array[$tag->id] = array_push($tag->value,$array[$tag->id]);
    }else{
      //if key is not assigned we will create key and push value
      $array[$tag->id] = $tag->value;
    }
  }

  //usage

  print_r($array[7]); // list tags with id 7

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a 2-dimensional array:

```
$array = array();

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $tag = $row['tag'];
    if (isset($array[$id])) {
        $array[$id][] = $tag;
    } else {
        $array[$id] = array($tag);
    }
}
```

The resulting `$array` will be

```
array(1 => array('ect'),
      7 => array('123', 'tag'),
      9 => array('lolly', 'hat'))
```